# Calling two methods with the same arity with null value

Tags: java

For the methods:

```
 public void doSomething(mObject1 ob){
 //Code A
 }

 public void doSomething(mObject2 ob){
 //Code B
 }
```

Whats the code executed when calling and why?

```
doSomething(null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot call doSomething with a null parameter. *The compiler will complain*. In all other cases the signature of the method is matched.However this would work :

```
doSomething((mObject1 )null);
```

Answer (score 4):

For overloaded methods, the one with most specific parameter types is called. Otherwise, if no method wins, it is considered ambiguous and a compiler error.

If you want to pass `null` you can select which method you want by casting the `null` expression or assigning it to a variable.

```
doSomething((MObject1)null);
doSomething((MObject2)null);

MObject1 m1 = null;
doSomething(m1);
MObject1 m2 = null;
doSomething(m2);
```

In your example if `MObject1` is a subtype of `MObject2` or vice versa, then it should compile.

(I am correctly correctly capitalising type names because that is the correct thing to do.)

Answer (score 4):

This depends. If one of `mObject1` and `mObject2` is a subtype of the other, the most specific method is chosen as per [Java Language Specification 15.12.2.5](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#301183).

If they are not related via inheritance, the method call is considered ambiguous and will cause a compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

It would turn into ambigious call compile time error

Answer (score 1):

It is compiler error.
However if one method argument is class and other is primitive datatype then results will change.

~Dheeraj